# React Native Image component not releasing memory

Tags: react-native

I am making a news app, each news article will have an image associated to it. I am loading them in flipkart's [recyclerlistview](https://github.com/Flipkart/recyclerlistview). The problem is Image component is loading images and memory keeps increasing, but the memory is not being released when I look into the android profiler, this is making app gets killed by the OS. The memory keeps increasing and going above the 200MB, sometimes going 300MB even. I am not sure really what is going wrong with Image component. I even have tried [react-native-fast-image](https://github.com/DylanVann/react-native-fast-image), but no luck. The memory keeps increasing.

This is how I am loading image into react-native-fast-image

```
        <FastImage
          source={{
            uri: 'xxxxx',
          }}
          style={{
            width: Dimensions.get('window').width,
            height: Dimensions.get('window').height,
          }}
        />
```

I am not really sure, if I have to add anything to above code.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a bug in react-native-fast-image itself as the [amount of open issues about memory leaks](https://github.com/DylanVann/react-native-fast-image/issues?q=is%3Aissue%20is%3Aopen%20memory) suggests... I am afraid there is not much you can do, other than waiting for a patch or submitting a pull request with a patch yourself.

You might try another version with `yarn add react-native-fast-image@x.x.x --exact`, however there is nothing about a memory leak in the changelog of the last few releases.

Comment: What about the RN's Image component? does it also has this bug?

Comment: No. At least not that I know of. Also I am using it in several apps and didn't have any issues yet.

Comment: Can you look into my code? what is the latest RN version you have used?

Comment: I've used 0.59 and 0.61 recently. If you don't have any special use case for react-native-fast-image I'd just use react-natives built in `Image` component. You shouldn't have any memory issues with that one (no matter which version).

Comment: I am using 0.62.2 now, But I am facing the issue. I have also observed, a blank app ( default introductory App.js code ) with no change in code also crossed 120MB memory, is it normal in RN?

Comment: That seems definitely high. Did you measure this for a debug build? I had values between 40 - 100mb for a non empty app in Googles prelaunch report. However this is a release build.